# nodejs express apps in small orange

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to "A Small Orange" and I am trying to run an express app in small orange following [this link](http://yakirac.me/2015/08/04/setting-up-a-nodeexpress-app-with-a-small-orange-web-hosting/)

I first created the following directory structure

/home/user/servercode/myapp with tmp directory and app.js file
/home/user/public_html/clientCode/myapp with .htaccess

/home/user/servercode/myapp/tmp contains an empty restart.txt file
In /home/user/servercode/myapp, I ran

```
npm init 
npm install express --save
```

This is my app.js. Pretty much same as the one in the link mentioned in the post

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World Express App');
});

if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) != 'undefined') {
    console.log( 'Example app listening with passenger' );
app.listen('passenger');
} else {
    console.log( 'Example app listening with 3000' );
    app.listen(3000);
}
```

.htaccess has 644 permission level and contains this

```
PassengerEnabled on
PassengerAppRoot /home/user/serverCode/myapp
SetEnv NODE_ENV production
SetEnv NODE_PATH /usr/lib/node_modules
```

When I try to access myapp, I get this error 
**Cannot GET /myapp/** and 404 in browser console

I could get a normal nodejs application running without express with the below content in app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});
server.listen(8000);
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

But not able to get express app running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add route in you application as :

```
app.get('/myapp', function(req, res){...});
```